# Is it possible to register a string as a UDF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

In Spark (Scala), after the application jar is submitted to Spark, is it possible for the jar to fetch many strings from a database table, convert each string to a catalyst Expression and then convert that expression to a UDF, and use the UDF to filters rows in another DataFrame, and finally union the result of each UDF?

(The said expression needs some or all columns of the DataFrame, but which columns are needed is unknown at the time of the code of the jar is written, the schema of the DataFrame is known at development time)

An example:

expression 1: `"id == 1"`

expression 2: `"name == \"andy\""`

DataFrame:

- row 1: id = 1, name = "red", age = null
- row 2: id = 2, name = "andy", age = 20
- row 3: id = 3, name = "juliet", age = 21

the final result should be the first two rows

Note: it is not acceptable to first concatenate the two expressions with a `or`, for I needed to track which expression results the result row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited:** Filter for each argument and union All.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test1.csv")

val args = Array("id == 1", "name == \"andy\"")
val filters = args.zipWithIndex

var dfs = Array[DataFrame]()

filters.foreach {
    case (filter, index) => 
        val tempDf = df.filter(filter).withColumn("index", lit(index))
        dfs = dfs :+ tempDf
}

val resultDF = dfs.reduce(_ unionAll _)
resultDF.show(false)

+---+----+----+-----+
|id |name|age |index|
+---+----+----+-----+
|1  |red |null|0    |
|2  |andy|20  |1    |
+---+----+----+-----+
```

---

**Original:** Why just put the string to the filter?

```
val df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").csv("test.csv")

val condition = "id == 1 or name == \"andy\""
df.filter(condition).show(false)

+---+----+----+
|id |name|age |
+---+----+----+
|1  |red |null|
|2  |andy|20  |
+---+----+----+
```

Something I have missed?

Comment: I should have mentioned that there are multiple (amount is unknown at development time) expressions to be executed in one jar, and the final result is the union of the result of each expression. I've updated the question. Thanks :)